# Get the selected checked value from the ul list in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am tring to use Vue.js in my project. But, I do not know how to **get the checked value in ul list from the dynamic API data**?

The getQuestion API is like this:

```
{

 "code": 0
 "data": {
 "question": [
  {
    "title": "Whick country are you in",
    "questionNo": "30",
    "answer": [
      {
        "answerNo": 1,
        "answerContent": "United States"
      },
      {
        "answerNo": 2,
        "answerContent": "China"
      },
      {
        "answerNo": 3,
        "answerContent": "Canada"
      },
      {
        "answerNo": 4,
        "answerContent": "Japan"
      },
      {
        "answerNo": 5,
        "answerContent": "England"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "What Programming Language Should a Beginner Learn？",
    "questionNo": "37",
    "answer": [
      {
        "answerNo": 1,
        "answerContent": "Python"
      },
      {
        "answerNo": 2,
        "answerContent": "JavaScript"
      },
      {
        "answerNo": 3,
        "answerContent": "Java"
      },
      {
        "answerNo": 4,
        "answerContent": "PHP"
      },
      {
        "answerNo": 5,
        "answerContent": "Ruby"
      }
    ]
  },

}
```

In html, the template is:

```
       <div class="ques-container" id="ques_container">
        <template v-for="(quesItem,index) in question">
            <div class="ques-item">
                <p class="title">{{index+1}}.{{quesItem.title}}</p>
                <ul class="answer-group" >
                    <template v-for="(answerItem,index) in quesItem.answer">
                        <li><input type="radio" :id="index+quesItem.questionNo"
                                   :name="quesItem.questionNo"
                                   :value="{questionNo:quesItem.questionNo,answerNo:answerItem.answerNo}"/><label
                                :for="index+quesItem.questionNo"><span></span>{{answerItem.answerContent}}</label>
                    </template>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </template>
    </div>
```

And the template had already rendered correctly, the result: [Result rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD06d.png)

When the user select one answer of every question, I will get the value of the selected answer value of every question to the backend API. But I do not know how to **get the checked value in ul list from the dynamic API data**? I think for this problem for a long time, but still have no idea.

Comment: Use [v-model](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox) to bind to a `selectedAnswer` property on each question or `selectedAnswers` array on global model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to save the **question number** and the **selected answer** in an array.

On the HTML, I added a `v-on:change` passing the question number and answer like so:

```
<input type="radio"
    v-on:change="selectAnswer(quesItem.questionNo,answerItem.answerNo)"/>
```

I also added an `answers` array in the data to store the selected answers. Then, I added a method `selectAnswer` to push the data to the array `answers`, like so:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#ques_container',
  data: {
    question: [...],
    answers: []
  },
  methods: {
    selectAnswer: function(qNo, qAns) {
        this.answers[qNo] = qAns;
    }
  }
});
```

Once the user completes the questionnaire and hits `Submit`, all you'll have to do is pass the `answers` array.

Here's a quick fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/zrum4nts/

To view the contents of the `answers` array, you'll have to open your browser console.

Comment: First,thanks for answer.I think maybe there are some problems when you add the data to array.Because all the answers of the every question are radio. when you execute the method "this.answers.push()", that means when you trigger the 'change' event of the radio, the value will be added to "this.answers".At last, every value that you trigger the 'change' event will be added to the array.

Comment: @zctocm I updated my answer and the fiddle. I changed the way the answers are being stored in the array. Let me know if this works for you or if you have additional questions.

Comment: @zctocm If this helped you please mark this as the accepted answer and an upvote would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah,I have accepted your answer,but I can not upvote because my reputation is less than 15,sorry about that. At last,thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @zctocm Thank you! :)